# Async loading a module property

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, ractivejs

I've defined a module (module1) which is supposed to load the value of a property asynchronously. How can I use this property in my app as soon as it is defined and only after it is defined?

## My setup (simplified)

### v1

***app.js***

```
require(['module1'], function(mod) {
    document.getElementById("greeting").value = mod.getPersonName();
});
```

***module1.js***

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    _person;

    $.get('values/person.json')
        .done(function(data) {
            _person = data
        });

    return {
        getPersonName: function() { return _person.name; }
    }
```

***values/person.json***

```
{ name: 'John Doe', age: 34 }
```

This only works if the GET happens nearly instantaneously, otherwise it fails because _person is undefined when getPersonName is called.

### v2

To counter this, I figured I would register a callback to notify the app when person was loaded.

***app.js***

```
require(['module1'], function(mod) {
    mod.onPersonLoaded(function() {
        document.getElementById("greeting").value = mod.getPersonName();
    });
});
```

***module1.js***

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    _person;
    _onLoaded;

    $.get('values/person.json')
        .done(function(data) {
            _person = data;
            _onLoaded();
        });

    return {
        getPersonName: function() { return _person.name; },
        onPersonLoaded: function(cb) { _onLoaded = cb; }
    }
}
```

This works if the GET is slow, however, if it's quick _onLoaded is undefined when `.done()` is called.

Is there a good way to use _person values in app.js as soon as they are defined and only once they are defined?

I'm using RequireJS, but my question is generally applicable to AMD.

## Edit

In simplifying my example, I removed a layer which may be important. I'm using RactiveJS for the UI.

### Setup (slightly less simplified)

***app.js***

```
require(['Ractive', 'module1'], function(Ractive, mod) {

    var ractive = new Ractive({
        ...
        data : {
            name: mod.getPersonName()
        }
    });

    ractive.observe(...);
    ractive.on(...);

});
```

## Edit 2

My current solution, subject to change. Register a callback that notifies app.js when person is loaded. Callback is called immediately if person is already loaded when callback is registered.

***app.js***

```
require(['Ractive', 'module1'], function(Ractive, mod) {

    var ractive = new Ractive({
        ...
        data : {}
    });

    mod.watchPerson(function() {
        ractive.set('person.name', mod.getPersonName());
    });

    ractive.observe(...);
    ractive.on(...);

});
```

***module1.js***

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    _person;
    _onLoaded;

    $.get('values/person.json')
        .done(function(data) {
            _person = data;
            try {
                _onLoaded();
            } catch (e) {
                // that was fast!
                // callback will be called when it is registered
        });

    return {
        getPersonName: function() { return _person.name; },
        watchPerson: function(cb) { 
            _onLoaded = cb;
            if(_person != null) {
                _onLoaded();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Promises are a good choice here because callbacks are *always* called asynchronously - you never encounter that confusing situation where `_onLoaded()` gets called before it's designed.

Unfortunately, jQuery's promise implementation doesn't adhere to the [Promises/A+ specification](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/), so you don't get that guarantee. If possible, you could use an alternative AJAX library like [Reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest), and do something like

**app.js**

```js
define(['module1'], function (mod) {
  mod.then(function(person) {
    // do something with person.name
  }
});
```

**module1.js**

```js
define(['reqwest'], function (reqwest) {
  return reqwest('values/person.json');
});
```

### Using the text loader plugin

Another option, since you're already using AMD, would be to use a loader plugin, such as [text](https://github.com/requirejs/text):

**app.js**

```js
define(['module1'], function (person) {
  // do something with person.name
});
```

**module1.js**

```js
define(['text!values/person.json'], function (personJSON) {
  return JSON.parse(personJSON);
});
```

### Using the text loader plugin

In fact there's even a [JSON plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/src/json.js), so you could do away with module1 entirely in this example situation:

**app.js**

```js
define(['json!values/person'], function (person) {
  // do something with person.name
});
```

Comment: Rich, thank you for Ractive! The values I'm loading are actually coming from the chrome.storage api, so the text loader plugin won't work for me; I figured an ajax example would be more broadly applicable and understood. Sorry for the head fake. I've opted for registering callbacks and immediately calling the callback if the value is defined when the callback is being registered, see my second edit above.

Comment: Ah, I see - no worries. That's bad form for chrome.storage to be inconsistent about whether callbacks happen synchronously or asynchronously. Isaac Schlueter wrote a [good blog post](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) about that... I shall consider myself forewarned if I ever have to use it. And you're welcome, glad you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this. Basically, it is not much different from your V2, but it adds more incapsulation.

**app.js**

```
require(['module1'], function(mod) {
    mod.loadPerson(function(person) {
        document.getElementById("greeting").value = person.getPersonName();
    });
});
```

**module1.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return {
        loadPerson : function(callback) {
            $.get('values/person.json').done(function(data) {
                  _person = data;

                 callback({
                    getPersonName: function() { return _person.name; }
                 });
            });

        }
    }
}
```

You may also use promises promises instead of simple callback.

Comment: Thanks. As I was typing up my question I had a similar thought. In simplifying my example I removed a layer, because I'm using ractive for the UI. Would you do the same using `app.js` from my edit? And setup ractive in the callback?

Comment: @Enrico Yes, I would. V1 is not an option, I think, unless you are using synchronous ajax.